# Data adding but not showing in listview

Tags: android

I am adding the data to list view once i recieve message. When listener call then i add message but its not displaying on the listview.

Please help me to solve this issue.

```
/**
     * It display the chat messages.
     */
     private void displayResultList() {
         if(messageList != null && messageList.size() > 0) {
             adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messageList) {
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        if (convertView == null) {
                            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
                        }
                        ((TextView)convertView).setText(getItem(position));
                        ((TextView)convertView).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        return convertView;
                    };
             };
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
         }
     }

     /**
      * This listener called when click on send button.
      */
     private OnClickListener sendListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                muc.sendMessage(chatMessage.getText().toString());
                messageDataSource.open();
                messageDataSource.createRoomMessage(roomName, chatMessage.getText().toString(), userId, null);
                messageDataSource.close();
                chatMessage.setText("");
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.v("HB", "Exception at::" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: datasource.notifyDataSourceChanged()

Comment: There is no object `datasource`. Please give explaination more. I added the adapter.notifyDataSourceChanged() but still its not adding to listview

Comment: hm. do you understand jow this works? as it looks you skipped RTFM step somehow...

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8370140/1276374 to see how it should be implemented

Comment: I set messageList.add(packet.getFrom().substring(packet.getFrom().indexOf("/") + 1) + " : " + ((Message) packet).getBody());
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but still nothing display on listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solve my problem. My problem was I was refresh the adapter listview in onclick listener of button..

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```