# SimpleDraweeView in ListView Item Display Wrong

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, fresco

I used `SimpleDraweeView` in `ListView` Item. If the header url is not null, it will display the image from the network, or it will display the default image from local drawable.

The code is as follow:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.info_contact_item,null);
            holder.ivHeader = findViewById(convertView, R.id.iv_header);
            holder.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (BaseViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final String url = data.get(position).get("headerUrl");
       if (StringUtil.isNull(url)){
            holder .ivHeader.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_head_icon);
       }else{
            ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse(uri))
                    .setAutoRotateEnabled(true) 
                    .setLocalThumbnailPreviewsEnabled(true) //
                    .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true) //
                    .build();
            DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                    .setImageRequest(imageRequest)
                    .setOldController(simpleDraweeView.getController())
                    .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
                    .build();
            holder.ivHeader.setController(controller);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

When I scroll `ListView` to the end, the `SimpleDraweeView` displays the same image as the last screen image data. Anybody has the same problem?

Comment: what is the `the last screen image data`?

Comment: six items will be displayed in screen, when I scroll listview to next six items,the 7th item's simpledraweeview display the 1th image data.

Comment: please post full sourcecode in your adapter. you should write a log for check if 7th item load correct url or not. did the 7th item load same url as the 1th image data

Comment: I checked the log, the url is correct. the 7th item url is null and the 1th is the correct url

Comment: I am not sure because I am never use if (StringUtil.isNull(url)). can you replace it by if (url == null){

Comment: the same as :TextUtils.isEmpty(url)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98898/discussion-between-phan-vn-linh-and-freddy).

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8370140/2930834) code, when you expect your `ListView` data should be updated, don't forget to call `notifydatasetchanged()` which will reflet the changes in `ListView`.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: ,thanks for helping, I didn't change the data,so there is no need to use notifydatasechanged() to refresh the listview,I just srcoll listview to the next screen item.